# Paypal Multi currencies button buy

Tags: html, css, button, paypal, currency

I created several buttons buy on Paypal with different currency.

Do you think, is it possible to create one by compiling the codes?

However, I'm a beginner in coding so...I'm a bit lost.

Button buy on paypal code is :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXCURRENCY">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I would like to configure a currency selection. I meant, if the buyer wants to buy in $ for example, he will select the currency and press the button buy for going to the paypal product in $

If the buyer wants to buy in € for example, he will select the currency and press the button buy for going to the paypal product in €

```
    Currency: 
    <select name="currency_code">
        
        <option value="EUR">EUR €</option>
        <option value="USD" selected>USD $</option>
    </select>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

Where I need to put this 2 lines?

```
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxUS">

<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxEUR">
```

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

For this, create an unhosted button.

Go to https://www.paypal.com/buttons , Buy Now button, set your options, and in Step 2 uncheck the option to 'Save your button at PayPal.

When your code is generated, click the option above to remove code protection.

Now all you need is a single `<select>` input to change the `currency_code`.  There will be no hosted_button_id